# Is there an easy way to select by histogram range in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, histogram, image-manipulation

The other day I was wondering if there is an easy way in GIMP to choose the pixels that are part of a selected range on the histogram.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to select by pixels' intensity range.

#### Step-by-step

1. Make a copy of the layer (Layer → Duplicate Layer)
2. Select the duplicate layer, apply threshold (Colors → Threshold) to select the range of intensities.
3. In Layer → Mask → Add Layer Mask (or right click in the list of layers). Select “Grayscale copy of layer” and “Invert mask”.
4. idem: Mask to selection.
5. Hide or remove the layer with mask.

#### An example:

Original image. I want to select the circle:

[image: Original image]

Make a copy of the layer:

[image: Duplicate layer]

Apply threshold. Note that the area to be selected is black:

[image: Threshold]

Add Layer Mask using the grayscale value of the image:

[image: Add Layer Mask]

Now you've obtained an image with the mask. Everything except the black circle is transparent (we can see the bottom layer through it):

[image: Image with the mask]

Convert the mask to selection. Switch to the original layer. The circle is selected.

[image: Mask to selection]

Answer (score 5):

There is a plugin called [Adagio Range Selection](http://registry.gimp.org/node/17513) that does pretty much what you want. You can't select from the histogram directly, but you can select the upper and lower boundaries.

[image]

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta!